# SSRS reports from multiple queries

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying work on a requirement using SSRS 2008 R2. The requirement is to create a detailed report which has main query(dataset1). And a column in this main query is used as a join or input to another query(dataset2).

I am trying to create a parameter and get the value for this from the main query or dataset1. How do I assign this parameter to dataset2? Also I will have similar situation to create dataset3, dataset4 etc and all this sub queries needs to be joined to dataset1.

Can you please help me what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dataset2, use a SQL variable in your query. SSRS will create a report parameter for you. Then go into this new report parameter and tell it that its available values should come from Dataset1.

Then repeat for the other datasets. :)